# How to insert and show data in the same form codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 <?php
                $att = array('id' => 'survey_form', 'role' => 'ajax-form');
                echo form_open('welcome/addsurvey', $att);
                ?>
                <div class="span5 offset1" id="form_div">
                    <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger reg_error">', '</div>'); ?>
                    <div class="form-group control-group warning">
                        <label for="SurveyTitle">Survey Title</label>
                        <input name="SurveyTitle" type="text" class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a Survey Title" id="SurveyTitle" required placeholder="Please enter the Survey Title" value="<?php echo set_value('SurveyTitle'); ?>">
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group control-group warning">
                        <label for="SurveyIntroduction">Survey introduction</label>
                        <textarea name="SurveyIntroduction" type="text" class="form-control" id="SurveyIntroduction" placeholder="Enter the Survey Introduction" value="<?php echo set_value('SurveyIntroduction'); ?>"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Add Survey</button>
                </div>
                </form>
```

I am inserting data via the form above it works fine how do i show the fields on the form after insertion via the set_value as it isn't working for me right now.

**Here is my controller function below:**

```
 public function addsurvey() {

    if (isset($_POST['SurveyTitle']) && isset($_POST['SurveyIntroduction'])) {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('SurveyTitle', 'Survey Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('SurveyIntroduction', 'Survey introduction', 'required');

        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Survey Title and Survey Introduction cannot be empty');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('SurveyPage');
        } else {

            $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $UserId = "m123456789";
            $SurveyTitle = $this->input->post('SurveyTitle');
            $SurveyIntroduction = $this->input->post('SurveyIntroduction');

            $SurveyLink = base_url() + rand() + $SurveyTitle;
            $isDisabled = 0;
            $db_query = $this->db->query("INSERT into survey(SurveyTitle,SurveyIntro,SurveyLink,DateCreated,CreatedBy,isDisabled) VALUES('" . $SurveyTitle . "','" . $SurveyIntroduction . "','" . $SurveyLink . "','" . $today . "','" . $UserId . "','" . $isDisabled . "')");

            if ($this->db->insert_id($db_query)) {
                $id = $this->db->insert_id();
                $lastid['last_id'] = $id;
            } else {

            }

            $data = $this->displayallsurveys();
            $surveydata = $this->getsurveydatabasedonId($id);
            $drpquestiontype = $this->displayquestiontypedropdown();
            $chkvalidations = $this->displayvalidationscheckboxes();
            $chkvalidationsother = $this->displayvalidationscheckboxesother();

            $parent_data = array('drpquestiontype' => $drpquestiontype, 'chkvalidations' => $chkvalidations, 'chkvalidationsother' => $chkvalidationsother, 'lastid' => $lastid);

            $parent_datasurveypage =array('data' => $data, 'surveydata' => $surveydata);
            $this->load->view('SurveyPage', $parent_datasurveypage);
            $this->load->view('question_data', $parent_data);
        }
    }
    else
    {

    $data = $this->displayallsurveys();
    $this->load->view('SurveyPage', array('data' => $data));

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393477/codeigniters-set-value-not-re-populating

Comment: i guess, set_value should must not be working for surveyintroduction. check the names again

Comment: use
$SurveyTitle = $this->input->post('SurveyTitle');
$SurveyIntroduction = $this->input->post('SurveyIntroduction');
$data['SurveyTitle'] = $SurveyTitle;
$data['SurveyIntroduction '] = $SurveyIntroduction ; and send $data to view and in input field get value with $SurveyTitle,$SurveyIntroduction

Comment: What if $data is empty?