# How do I use CodeIgniter's `set_value()` function when using `form_validation.php`?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

## Problem:

I've got a form I'm trying to [re-populate via the CodeIgniter docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#re-populating-the-form), and I'm trying to use the `set_value()` function in my view file, but I receive an error: `Message: Call to undefined function set_value()`.

I saw elsewhere on StackOverflow solutions to a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19393767) when using the `set_rules()` function to define validations on a field-by-field basis.

However, I've got all of my validations together in `config/form_validation.php`, as [sets of rules](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#creating-sets-of-rules). Because all of my validations are defined within the rule set, it seems a little different than when defining field-by-field.

My rule set, controller, model and view methods are below.

**Any idea why my re-population is not working?**

Thanks for any insight anyone can offer, I'm new to CodeIgniter and I might be misunderstanding how things are working.

---

### Validation Rules via `config/form-validation.php`:

```
$config = array(
  'create' => array (
    array(
      'field' => 'name',
      'label' => 'product name',
      'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[5]',
    ),
    array(
      'field' => 'description',
      'label' => 'product description',
      'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[5]',
    ),
    array(
      'field' => 'price',
      'label' => 'product price',
      'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[1]|less_than[100000]|decimal',
    ),
  ),
);
```

### In my Controller:

```
  public function create()
    {
    // XSS FILTER $POST OBJECT
    $new_product = $this->input->post(null, true);

    // SEND TO MODEL
    $this->load->model("Product_model");
    $product = $this->Product_model->add_product($new_product);

    // IF VALIDATIONS RETURN FALSE, STORE ERRORS IN FLASH SESSION
    if ($product[0] === FALSE)
    {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', $product[1]);
      redirect("/products/new");
    }

    // IF VALIDATION PASSES, SEND HOME
    redirect("/");
  }
```

### In my Model:

```
 public function add_product($product)
  {

    $this->load->library("form_validation");

    if ($this->form_validation->run("create") === FALSE) 
    {

      // STORE ERRORS & SHIP BACK TO CONTROLLER:
      return array(FALSE, validation_errors());
    } 
    else 
    {
      // Success, Escape strings and insert to DB and return TRUE (or item)
    }
  }
```

### In my form View:

(*The page which displays returned errors above the form*)

```
 <form action="./create" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>">
  <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="10" value="<?php echo set_value('description'); ?>"></textarea>
  <input type="number" name="price" id="price" value="<?php echo set_value('price'); ?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Comment: for validations use model  and for products use controller.

Comment: You have the form validation in wrong area should be on controller not in model. as explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller

Comment: @Mr. ED Thanks for your response/help here. I've learned in other full-stacks to put validations into Models...at least this is how I tend to do things in JS/Python stacks, etc. I have seen some folks with CI have this debate, about validation going in controller, but I've also seen examples in CI where it's done in the Model. I believe it should be possible to achieve what I want validating in the Model. I even tried moving my logic into the controller (and creating a single rule for the validation rather than use the rule arrays). Still no luck. I'm probably missing something basic...hmm

Comment: @Mr. ED I did add `form_helper` to autoload per pradeep's feedback, so it seems I now have access to the `set_value()` function in my View, but unfortunately the data isn't populating. If I set a second parameter as a default value, that will populate, but the field data itself will not. This even occurs when I moved the validation to the controller itself, and even when I tried writing a single rule rather than use the rule arrays. It seems like its setup correctly, I must be missing something...Thank you again for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

add `form_helper` in your `controller` or in `autoload.php`

In controller :

```
     public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
     }
```

Or in autoload.php :

```
    $autoload['helper'] = array('form','url');
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#re-populating-the-form

Comment: Thanks for this. I added `form_helper` to my autoload, and this did remedy the error message (the `set_value()` function now appears to run without error), but unfortunately the proper form value is not being propagated (just ends up empty). I did try setting a default value within `set_value('foo', 'default')` as a second parameter, and the default value does appear, so the function is running. I'm not sure why my data isn't re-populating: the rules functions are running, I can receive my validation errors, etc. I even tried creating individual rules and putting logic in controller.

Comment: I'll have to step back a bit and think more...I mean, things *appear* to be setup correctly...as noted, I even tried creating an individual rule (rather than use `form-validation.php`), but still not working...hmmm...I'm sure I'm overlooking something basic...if all else fails I guess I could flash the form data to session for a quick and dirty solution, but was wanting to embrace CI's tools. Thank you greatly for your time responding, means a lot!

Comment: Update: After more exploring with `form_helper`, I understand now how to properly use set_value(). I was unfortunately only half-embracing form_helper and have learned since :) Thank you!